# Give every question in a Google-Form an unique id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to make a Google Form using Google Apps Scripts. The questions in the form comes from a Google Sheet which includes the id and text of a question. When the form is submitted and I export the questions to a sheet the column names are the questions as text. I would rather replace them using an unique ID based on a column from my own Google Sheet where the questions are also stored as text.

How can I solve this?

Comment: add a date/timestamp of when the form was submitted (as a hidden field)

Comment: Build a hash table from the text of the question and the id to convert questions into id's very quckly.

Answer (score 2):

#### Build a Question Text to ID hash table

```
function hashtable() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let texttoid = {};
  sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().forEach(r => texttoid[r[1]]=r[0]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(texttoid));
}

Execution log
11:58:17 AM Notice  Execution started
11:58:18 AM Info    {"text1":"id0","text2":"id1","text3":"id2","text4":"id3","text5":"id4","text6":"id5","text7":"id6","text8":"id7","text9":"id8","text10":"id9","text11":"id10"}
11:58:18 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Sheet0:

| id0 | text1 |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | text2 |
| id2 | text3 |
| id3 | text4 |
| id4 | text5 |
| id5 | text6 |
| id6 | text7 |
| id7 | text8 |
| id8 | text9 |
| id9 | text10 |
| id10 | text11 |

You can goto to [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and using the search box find any function that you don't understand. If it's a pure JavaScript function the go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

You could store the hash table in cache if wish to use it repeatedly to save the time of building it each time from a spreadsheet.